# Shorts since install

Tags: jeep, remote-start

I recently had a remote starter installed on my jeep. Every since I have had shorts in my wiring. I was told keyless starter are bad on starters. Last week I had to jump start my jeep 2 times. I replaced 1 battery terminal, since then my keyless starter won't start or lock or unlock my jeep. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you're having problems with the operation of the remote starter and you had someone do the work for you, take it back to them and ensure they fix the issues. Obviously they didn't do something correctly and you haven't received what you've paid for. On a separate note, for me personally, if a car didn't come with a remote start, I won't have one installed or install one myself. The reason? Because with most of them you have to butcher the wiring harness to make it work and then you run into issues like you're having.

Comment: I would not fit one either, after market burglar alarms used to cause SO much grief... If you are in a cold area as I am, then I fitted a small ceramic 400W heater under the bonnet - timer puts it on 3 hours before I leave for work... cheap and easy...